# how can I make a mesh from curves?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to mesh a rear wing of a vintage car.
I've done some Bezier curves and converted them into mesh. I have the same amount of vertices, so I should be able to connect everything together but I can't find how to do it...

[image]

So, I did Convert the curves to a mesh by pressing 'ALT+C, but when I press F it goes like this:

[image]
Bridge Edge Loop doesn't work either

thanks

Comment: u mean u want to fill that curve with mesh

Comment: Yes. Id like a mesh, following my curves,

Comment: have you tried grid fill?

Comment: it says: loops are not connected by wire/boundary edge ?

Comment: i think curve volume addon work perfect for you to create mesh but its not free https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0E_xtdV57_M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so I finally found what I missed.
I needed to select the curves in *Edit Mode*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, *Grid Fill* and set the correct number of span and offset in order to get the shape.
It was only possible in two steps because I had my guiding line in the middle so I did one half and then the other.

Thanks for helping me
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: example of the process]

Activate the builtin **F2** add-on from Blender by searching "F2" in the user preferences.

After that convert the curve to a mesh (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).

Then make a face out of the beginning of the loop (<kbd>F</kbd>) and select the new edge.

Now press <kbd>F</kbd> repeatedly until it closes the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy/automated way to do this, however you can follow these steps to do a manual workaround.

1. Convert the curve to a mesh by pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
   [image: converting the curve]
2. In *'edit mode'* you can select the egdes you want to connect and then press <kbd>F</kbd> to add a face between them.
   [image: adding faces]
3. To add additional edge loops you can select the edges you wish and do a subdivide. (Specials shortcut <kbd>W</kbd>)
   [image: subdividing]

tip: to bridge multiple loops you can use the 'bridge edge loops' function (menu shortcut <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>)
[image: bridging edge loops]